# Embed icon in PySympleGui

Tags: pysimplegui

is there a way to embed icon in PySympleGUI or only external file, Im hit my head to do it but I don't know if is possible, can someone help with this?

Thanks all!

Comment: I'm sure this is in the PySimpleGUI documentation.

Answer (score 1):

there is the following way, use example images :

[sg. Image(r'filename',background_color=Colors.background)]

it helps you.